# How to use a child object field as part of the compound key in another child in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need to create a new Many-To-One relationship on my User entity which joins against another entity. The problem is the other entity has a compound key of which 1 field is a field in the User entity and the other is a field in another Many-To-One entity.

User.Key -> User.NewThing.Key

User.SubThing.Key -> User.NewThing.Key

Below is the invalid mapping file I am ideally wanting to use where JeanieUserTyped is my newthing and the ApplicationId is the key in question which comes from ShortCode.ApplicationId.

Question is how do I tell it to map the application part of the compound key?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="JeanieMaster.Domain.Entities" assembly="JeanieMaster.Domain">
    <class name="JeanieUser" table="DBSVR1.Jeanie_Master.dbo.JeanieUser" select-before-update="false" optimistic-lock="none">
        <id name="Id" column="UserId" type="Int32">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>

        <property name="Mobile" type="String"/>
        <property name="UniqueReoccurBillingRefId" type="String"/>
        <property name="DateJoined" type="DateTime"/>
        <property name="IsActive" type="Boolean"/>

        <many-to-one name="MobileNetwork" class="MobileNetwork" column="MobileNetworkId" />
        <many-to-one name="ShortCode" class="ShortCode" column="ShortCodeId" />
        <many-to-one name="MobileHandset" class="MobileHandset" column="HandsetId" />

        <many-to-one name="JeanieUserTyped" class="JeanieUserTyped">
            <column name="Mobile" />
            <column name="ApplicationId" />
        </many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you give more details, sounds like you have 3 entities,

User
SubThing
NewThing

Where NewThing resolves a Many-to-Many with User and SubThing - am I close?

Maybe like this:

```
User         -<  SubThing
 |                   | 
 /\                  /\
        NewThing
```

I don't suppose the [composite key stuff in nhibernate is relevant?](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid)

Comment: I've added a more specific edntry to my question